# Run “svn log”，why the revision number is not continuous in the returned messages？

Tags: logging, svn

I checked out the trunk of the tc8.5.x from Tomcat source code repository, and run "svn log" in the trunk to see all revision commits log, the returned messages  are as follows:

---

**r1834283** | markt | 2018-06-25 15:30:01 +0800 (一, 25  6 2018) | 1 line

### ...

**r1834199** | rjung | 2018-06-23 20:29:57 +0800 (六, 23  6 2018) | 5 lines

### ...

I want to know why did not record the all continuous revision number? What happened to missing revision number?

Comment: Please elaborate on "I downloaded the Tomcat repository" and "svn log". What did you checkout and where are you doing the `svn log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Apache Software Foundation SVN repository is a large monolithic repository that holds around **200 separate projects** and **contains more than 1,800,000 revisions**. Tomcat is just one of many open-source projects the repository has. Therefore, you did not actually "download" or checkout the Tomcat repository - you checked out Tomcat project from the ASF repo.

The revisions you see belong to the commits made to Tomcat codebase. Revisions that you don't see are not related to Tomcat codebase, but to other projects in the repository and your working copy does not have them. Therefore, you don't see those revisions when you view the log.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question, yesterday when I checked out the trunk from the tomcat codebase, it noticed me as follow: Checked out revision 1834282. Today I checked out again, it noticed me:Checked out revision 1834502. However, when I run "svn log ", both of them do not appear in the newest commit log. Why do not record above revisions?